# Why the same .sh does not work with 2 different users executing it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, users, .sh

I have rwo users User1 and User2.

I have this script1.sh inside User2 home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user1 && ./script2.sh
```

that calls script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 2 > 1 ]; then
echo TRUE!.
else
echo NOT TRUE!
fi
```

Now, when I execute script1 using user1, everything works. When I execute with user2 i get this error:

```
./script2.sh: line 3: 1: Permission denied
```

Saying I can't.. IF? If I write everything on the terminal, it also works.
So my permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user2 group_with_both_users 149 Ago 19 02:41 script2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user2 group_with_both_users 60 Ago 19 01:38 script1.sh
```

I really have no clue of what is going on.

Comment: Do the directories have proper permissions?

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
if [ 2 > 1 ]; then
```

causes the shell to try and open a file named `1` for writing. Read the section `REDIRECTION` in the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output) for an explanation. Your `user1` apparently is allowed to write to that file, and `user2` isn't.

You were probably thinking of this:

```
if [ 2 -gt 1 ]; then
```

Which tests whether 2 is greater than 1, which is obviously true except for very large values of 1.

Answer (score 0):

**The following expressions are used with integers:**
Table 27-3 (from [tlcl's](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) [pdf book](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/13.07/TLCL-13.07.pdf/download)):

```
Integer Expressions:

Expression             Is True If...
integer1 -eq integer2 integer1 is equal to integer2.
integer1 -ne integer2 integer1 is not equal to integer2.
integer1 -le integer2 integer1 is less than or equal to integer2.
integer1 -lt integer2 integer1 is less than integer2.
integer1 -ge integer2 integer1 is greater than or equal to integer2.
integer1 -gt integer2 integer1 is greater than integer2.
```

So, You have to use **`-gt`** instead of `>` in **if expression**.